# Sum every 50th row in a column where the column also contains text - Excel

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have a workbook full of invoices, formatted for printing, and I need to sum the Total Due for all 295 invoices. The first Total Due is in H22 with the next amount 50 cells below in H71 (not including H22.) The rest of Column H contains the individual amounts that compose the Total Due and various text. Like this:

```
Charges
10
20
30
Amount Due:
$60.00
```

If it would be easier to sum the range that makes up the total, that works too.

Each range is 10 rows, H11:H20. Then 50 below that at H60:69.

Edit: Cell H22, not H32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(ROW($H$1:INDEX($H:$H,MATCH(1E+99,$H:$H)))-1,50)=21,$H$1:INDEX($H:$H,MATCH(1E+99,$H:$H))))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when Exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Comment: It worked. I don't have anything to check it against, but it looks right. Thank you!

Comment: @RonL the main things: `50` is your spacing and `21` is the row of the starting point - 1.  Then if your data is spaced exactly every 50 it will work.

Comment: the data is spaced evenly. I asked someone who added the totals manually and they match. I understand most of what's going on there, but can you explain the [1E+99]  part of the MATCH() function?

Comment: Because it is an array formula we need to make the referenced range as small as possible so the `$H$1:INDEX($H:$H,MATCH(1E+99,$H:$H))` sets the reference range to H1 to the last cell in column h with a number in it.  As the last row with a number changes so will the reference range so we do not do any unneeded calcs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBA. Create a new module, and paste in:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function sum_with_gaps(r As Range, gapSize As Integer, dataSize As Integer) As Double
    Dim ret As Double, i%
    ret = 0
    i = 1
    Do While i + dataSize - 1 <= r.Count
        ret = ret + WorksheetFunction.Sum(r.Range(r.Cells(i - 1, 1), r.Cells(i + dataSize - 1, 1)))
        i = i + dataSize + gapSize
    Loop
    sum_with_gaps = ret
End Function
```

Test data:

```
a
5.1
5.2
5.3
5.4
b
b
6.1
6.2
6.3
6.4
c
c
7.1
7.2
7.3
7.4
d
=sum_with_gaps(A2:A17,2,4)
```